# How to add timestamps to sailjs join table?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am developing an api for my android application and was wondering if there was a way I could add timestamps to the join table in sailsjs in many to many association.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean "the join table"? Show some model schema. And explain more.

Comment: You can add attribute time_stamp with default value to your model like: `time_stamp: {type: 'datetime', defaultsTo: function (){return Date.now(); }}`

Comment: Maxali .. I have users table having many to many association with groups table. I want to know when a user joins a particular group and hence I want to add time stamps to the join table(group_users__user_groups) which in this case is by default generated by sails.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thread on github where you can find the answer :

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3503